# Checking if the frame already exist in frame list

Tags: python, list, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I want to capture all the frames through my webcam until any frame is repeated I have tried this approach, but this is giving me error

> if frame not in frame_list: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
frame_list = []  #creating the list of frame
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        if frame not in frame_list:
            frame_list.append(frame)  #This list contain all the frames
        else : break
```

Comment: What does “all the frames” mean? How do you mean to compare frames? Should this be exact pixel equality, or is this an approximate equality?

Comment: Apprroximate could work. All frames means all the captured frames. I will change the frames through webcam gradually.

Comment: What does "all the captured frames" mean? You need to explain in more detail what you are doing. Are you capturing a specific number of frames, and then reading them into a list (which is what "all the captured frames" indicates to me), or are you capturing frames until you get a frame that is identical to a previous frame (which is what your code seems to indicate)?

Comment: The code is capturing all the frames by a rotating surveillance camera until it get all the frames which the camera covers while moving.

Comment: Does the camera rotate at a fixed speed? If so, you just need to figure out from the video feed how many frames there are in 360 degrees. Comparing frames to see if you’ve gone all the way around is probably the wrong approach. You will not get two identical frames, they will most likely be shifted. Also illumination can change, and things can move around in the space you’re recording in.

Comment: Yeah, understood. how to take all the frames in the 360 degrees. Is there any library for that?

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
present = (any((frame == frame_list).all() for x in frame_list)) #Checks if array is present in list

if present == False:
    frame_list.append(frame)  #This list contain all the frames
else : break
```

Comment: This would be hugely expensive if there's more than a few frames.

Comment: What about this: ```present = any(frame is x for x in frame_list)```?

Comment: I still don't know what OP actually wants to do, but if comparing to many frames, I'd compute a checksum for each frame, it's cheap to compare checksums, as opposed to comparing full images. But again, I don't know what OP wants to do, so I'm not recommending you change your answer just yet.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Okay